# Alphanumerical order for C++ characters

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison, character

What is the order followed by comparisons between characters in C++? I have noticed that 'z' > '1'. I am trying to find a link to the order rationale C++ follows for all characters, or any generic material reference in case this is a widely known order (similar to alphabetical order for lowercase letters).

Answer (score 0):

Each character in any programming language corresponds to an ASCII value. Just check this table, it will solve all of your doubts on how characters are evaluated https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Unless there's been a recent change (C++20 standard - looking into it), an implementation is *not required* to use the ASCII character set. But there are certain rules that must be obeyed, such as that the digits `0` thru `9` are in a continuous sequence.

Comment: thanks for your contribution @sbluff. Why 'z'>'1' then? Looking at this table I see 'z' listed before '1'

Comment: @Arnold `1` is around 40 and `z` is around 110... (I don't remember the exact number)

Comment: z is 0x7A (122 in decimal) and 1 is 0x31 (49 in decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Only `'0'` to `'9'` is guaranteed to be encoded consecutively. Other characters, according language specification, would be implementation specified. However almost all x86 c compilers use the ASCII code.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @user12986714. I understand there is not a natural order in the set, that is why I want to know which convention is specifically used in c++